# add an arabic abstract in TOC type document book

Tags: table-of-contents, arabic

I have to add in my thesis an abstract with 3 languages (french (my main language), english, arabic)
I treid to add the arabic abstract but it gives me an error. How can I fix this problem?  I used let\clear to have the 3 abstract in the same page because i'm working in book document
Thnak you for your help

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[arabic, english, french]{babel}
\newcommand{\ab}{\selectlanguage{arabic}}
\newcommand{\fr}{\selectlanguage{french}}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}} 
 \begin{document}

  \pagenumbering{roman}
 \clearpage
 \setcounter{page}{2}

 \chapter*{Résumé}
 \fr
  Droit des affaires

    \textbf{Mots clés : } 

      \ab
  {\let\clearpage\relax\chapter*{ملخص}}

قانون الاعمال

  \textbf{   : كلمات مفاتيح} 
   \en
   {\let\clearpage\relax\chapter*{Abstract}}

  law 
   \textbf{Keywords : } 
   \fr
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Résumé}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ملخص}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table des matières}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\textRL`  in `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textRL{ملخص}}`

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[arabic, english, french]{babel}
\newcommand{\ab}{\selectlanguage{arabic}}
\newcommand{\fr}{\selectlanguage{french}}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}} 
 \begin{document}

  \pagenumbering{roman}
 \clearpage
 \setcounter{page}{2}

 \chapter*{Résumé}
 \fr
  Droit des affaires

    \textbf{Mots clés : } 

      \ab
  {\let\clearpage\relax\chapter*{ملخص}}

قانون الاعمال

  \textbf{   : كلمات مفاتيح} 

   \en
   {\let\clearpage\relax\chapter*{Abstract}}

  law 
   \textbf{Keywords : } 
   \fr
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Résumé}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textRL{ملخص}}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table des matières}

  \tableofcontents
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much sir :)

Comment: @Siham Pleased to see that your problem is solved :)

Comment: yes indeed alalh bless you :)